# What structures form due to the melting of subducting plates?

Tags: geology, geophysics, plate-tectonics, tectonics

What structures form from the melting of subducting plates? 
Plutons, Accretionary wedges, Deep sea trenches, Faults?

Comment: homework questions are expected to show some attempt to answer the question on your own.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework questions are expected to show some effort to answer the question prior to posting.

Answer (score 5):

The subducting plate never really melt. It just gets recycled into the mantle (the [Asthenosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asthenosphere) to be more precise), which is in solid state. It is plastic and deformable enough to allow convection flows, but it is solid.

Beside more mantle, something that forms from the subducting plate is magma. The water contained in the subducted slab (that was once ocean floor) can lower the melting point of the mantle and allow it to melt and form magma. The magma is liquid and less dense than the surrounding mantle, therefore it rises through it, and then through the continental plate. Once there it can create plutons, batholiths and feed volcanoes if it make it all the way to the surface.
[image]
But what melts is mostly the mantle mixed with water from the subducting plate, not the subducting plate itself.

Comment: "This magma, been liquid and less dense than the surrounding mantle will rise trough it and the trough the crust too."   ???

Comment: @farrenthorpe Can you explain what you don't understand from that sentence?

Comment: Share it with a native English speaker.  I'm not sure what you are trying to say there.

Comment: @farrenthorpe I just edited it. Does it makes sense now? If you get what I mean please edit it to make it proper English.

Comment: I think you mean "through", not "trough".  Editing it now.

Comment: To underscore your point, there's [this NASA article](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a000000/a002400/a002410/) showing the results of their modeling where the remnants of the [Farallon Plate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farallon_Plate) are under North America today.